# Performance difference between 32-bit and 64-bit OS when i use Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, visual-studio-2010, operating-system

Is there a performance difference between 32-bit and 64-bit operating system when I use `Visual Studio 2010` ? (Mostly working with `.NET` and `C#`)

Comment: There shouldn't even be a question of 32 bit or 64 bit OS at this point.

Comment: Removed subjective part of the question

Comment: If you would buy a good new pc it performances would be reduced on a 32 bit OS for example the most obvious possibility for bigger memory. And like Mr. Disappointment said visual studio is only available in 32 bit

Comment: I personally notice a huge difference when I dont have at least 4gb of ram.

Comment: +1 for good question, while being too subjective. A 30 sec googling session will reveal almost all the info out there.

Comment: Read this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/


and this post especially [Visual Studio: Why is there no 64 bit version?][1]


  [1]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't know all implication, but one major benefits of the 64bits is that the process can go further than 2GB of memory.

When you have dozens of plugins, or large projects with heavy process (Resharper real-time analysis for my experience), this can be a large benefits to go beyond 2GB of ram.

Also, 64bits will allow you to beyond the <4GB limitation of the OS..

Comment: Yup, a good dev machine should have at a bare minimum 4gb, preferably 8+

Comment: @Allen: can I quote you to my boss :p

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that none of the tools are actually available in a 64-bit version.  It must be the new car smell.

Comment: Fine, none of the tools are available in 64 bit, but 64 bit will allow the OS to use more RAM overall and that means he can have more programs open, like MSSQL, LinqPad, 3 browsers, one or more instances of visual studio, god knows how many instances of cassini, etc.  Last time I looked it was about $200 for 12gb of top of the line "gaming" RAM.  If they can't afford that... ouch.

Comment: @Steve IDK about nowadays, but some of the big name pc manufacturers used to build machines geared towards software development and they probably have tons of marketing speak about higher requirements for developers.  I'd look there for ammo

Comment: @Allen: when you work on laptop, moving from 4GB to 8GB or even to 12 GBis far more expensive than on a desktop... but it's a long story

Answer (score 2):

Taking a risk answering this, I think, but...

Visual Studio is only available in 32-bit, and so runs as such in either environment. I'm certain Windows is very well optimised for running 32-bit applications in the WOW64 emulator.

Indeed, it performs well enough for me to be productive.

For some information on this from MSDN, [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384219(v=vs.85).aspx); neatly, this states:

> Processor hardware. Instruction
> emulation is performed on the chip. On
> the x64 processor, instructions are
> executed natively by the
> micro-architecture. Therefore,
> execution speed under WOW64 on x64 is
> similar to its speed under 32-bit
> Windows. On the Intel Itanium
> processor, more software is involved
> in the emulation, and performance
> suffers as a result.

Though this is not an exhaustive explanation. The link covers more ground regarding the variability.

Comment: visual studio works faster in 32 bit OS, as the bus carraying data takes 32 bits at a time in contrast of 64 bits in 64 bit os.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment You voted to close this question and then you answered it?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment Meta seems to say that the best thing to do when doing that is to make your answer a community wiki. Edit: I don't mind either way, I was just curious and I looked it up on meta and thought i'd share :)

Comment: @Allen: I do follow meta as I can, and like to follow the rules, but just like _The Pirate Code_, the rules there are more like guidelines, anyway. We have to use some circumstantial reasoning. ;)

Comment: Answers follow questions as they are migrated? Nice, didn't know that, makes sense though

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be the general consensus that its not that big of a deal anyway, it just struck me as very odd at first glance.  Now that I think about it, I'm almost sure I've done it once or twice myself.

Answer (score -1):

Here at work, he have 32 bit and 64 bit boxes, some with Windows XP, some with Windows 7. Even though we work with quite big solutions, I can assure you that we can't notice any significant difference in performance. Nevertheless, @SteveB's right about going beyond the memory limitation, so I'd say go 64 bits.